# Images are not displayed properly in .net 5

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net5

In one control I try to display images using JavaScript. Everything is fine as long as I am in the URL controller

> https://localhost:44300/Campaigns

But when I refer to the `index`, the images are not displayed, even though I am on the same page or after the `Redirect ("Index")`.

> https://localhost:44300/Campaigns/index

The root address does not seem to be working properly

This is my image address when it works properly in `Campaigns`

> https://localhost:44300/uploads/f09ef469-0893-4089-8491-78707d097b0e.jpg

This is my image address when it does not work properly in `Campaigns/Index`

> https://localhost:44300/Campaigns/uploads/f09ef469-0893-4089-8491-78707d097b0e.jpg

The CSS and js address images in the layout work well, and I used `UseStaticFiles()` in the `Configure`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you are referring to the images with a URL that is relative to your current page. You need to use a URL that is relative to your site root. You can change this by prefixing the URL with `/` where you are constructing them.

Eg instead of something like

```
uploads/f09ef469-0893-4089-8491-78707d097b0e.jpg
```

Use

```
/uploads/f09ef469-0893-4089-8491-78707d097b0e.jpg
```